# Web Application caching Integrated mode aspx pages

Tags: asp.net, browser-cache, cache-control, outputcache

We have an asp.net web application running on **ASP.NET 4.0** Integrated mode.
Sometimes ASPX pages are getting cached on client machines, before moving to *integrated* mode we were using *classic* mode and things were working fine. Suddenly aspx pages are getting cached after moving to integrated mode.

Comment: Did you migrate to IIS 7.5?  That seems to be culprit.  It adds a header to Cache-Control of no-cache="Set-Cookie" and that is causing our app to exhibit problems.  If that is case for you and you find a solution, I'm eager to hear it.  Going on 4 days of Googling and experimenting with no luck.

Comment: @Terry We have done one work around added  Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache); in master page Page_Load event

Comment: That's actually not so much a workaround as the answer. You can also configure that at the app, site, or server level.